# Cache lib that supports custom eviction trigger or provides next evictable key

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am building a cache based storage server (in java) that accepts client requests and stores data in the corresponding files on disk. The file metadata is small and can be cached in memory. However, if the disk size reaches a limit, I would like to explicitly evict the next evictable entry in the cache. Most cache libraries offer eviction by cache size or eviction by time, however I want a custom eviction trigger policy. I don't plan on implementing any cache algorithm (if possible).

I surveyed several java caching libraries but they don't provide an option for custom eviction trigger policy or a method that returns the `nextEvictableKey()`. The closest example would be guava library [here](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L2652) but I cannot access it from the application because its at 'default' access.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: So you would never want an entry to be evicted, except in the case where disk usage reaches some limit? And the cache *doesn't* contain the data which is in the files? And always has an entry for every file? Perhaps an actual caching library is overkill, and you could just use a Map with the last access time in its value, and scan the Map when you want to delete a file (as scanning the Map is cheap compared to any disk operation)

Comment: Why do you want a custom eviction policy?  The point of most caches is that they have their own eviction policy, smarter than what you might write yourself.

Comment: You need data to justify this requirement, because a [modern policy](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency) can make very smart decisions. If you can acquire traces, then you can use a [simulator](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Simulator) to look for improvement opportunities. In Guava (or Caffeine), you can use a `Weigher` that provides the file size and a `maximumWeight` to bound the cache by, and have a `RemovalListener` callback to delete the file on eviction. This would abstract the algorithms while solving your actual goal.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think the reason is that the cache content is the files on disk, not the data in memory, so the in memory 'cache' can't make eviction decisions, as it doesn't know when the storage limit has been reached.

Comment: @tgdavies That is why a logical limit based on the entry's "weight" can be used instead. The cache will trigger an eviction not on the number of entries, `Map.size()`, but on the accumulated weight.

Comment: @BenManes interesting, yes weigher and maximumWeight look like they'd do what the OP wants.

Comment: Let me explore the Weigher and maximumWeight idea, looks promising. I think what I really want is a custom eviction trigger policy, most caches offer based on size or time and both of which don't work for my case. I don't want to implement the 'Map' myself as I don't want to loose the eviction schemes implemented by these smart cache libraries already.

Comment: The weight of a KV is a static value and determined only once at the insertion. Is there any way to make it dynamic? In my example - the weight of key varies with the current size of file and total weight is the total disk space.
Also, are there any other cache libraries that offer the same feature?

Comment: What if you `invalidate` the cache entry when the file size changes? (I'm assuming that you take an action to change the file size)